# "Could not enter folder" mounted with sshfs from Kompare

Tags: 20.04, mount, filesystem, sshfs

I have a remote folder mounted as

```
sshfs mmatrosov@server: /home/mmatrosov/vm
```

When I try to open a file in Kompare and navigate into this folder, Kompare gives me an error message

```
Could not enter folder /home/mmatrosov/vm
```

However, I can freely browse this folder with Files and other programs. Also, Kompare sees "regular" (ext4) folders and files just fine. What is the problem?

```
Ubuntu 20.4
Kompare 4.1.3
SSHFS version 2.10.0
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
```